# Redirect www to non-www not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm trying to redirect from www.mydomain.com to mydomain.com but I keep failing. I used default Laravel htaccess file and I modified it to remove www from my links.
Can someone tell me what's wrong here:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
<FilesMatch "\.(html|php|txt|xml|js|css)$">
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
</FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Your rule for `www` should be working (seems correct to me). Does trailing-slash-rule work ? Do you have any error or unexpected behaviour ?

Comment: No errors, everything is ok, except when I visit my site with www, browser reports that site is not found.

Comment: Did you configure correctly your `www` subdomain ?

Comment: @JustinIurman I didn't, this is my first website so I don't know how to configure www subdomain

Comment: Well i think your problem is not coming from your htaccess. Actually, you can't access your website via `www` but it's ok via `domain.com` (without `www`). You'll have to configure Apache correctly

Comment: Can you guide me how to configure Apache so I redirect properly

Comment: Search for `httpd.conf` or `apache2.conf` file and find this line `ServerName example.com` (maybe in a `VirtualHost` block). Replace it by those 2 lines `ServerName www.example.com`   `ServerAlias example.com`. Now restart your server, you should be able to reach `www` version. Also, make sure to enable htaccess (`AllowOverride All`)

Comment: I'm trying to find that file since yesterday but it's missing. I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 with Laravel Forge. When I go to /etc, there is no apache2 folder. Is there any other location for apache2.conf?